# Пробежаться по словарю, отображению (Map)

Tags: java, коллекции, map, java-hashmap, hashmap

Помогите разобраться пример:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(1, "Vasilisa");
        map.put(2, "Marina");
        map.put(3, "Kate");

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
        }
```

Из Java docs, не очень с техническим английским поэтому пользуюсь переводчиком.

> Метод Map.entrySet возвращает коллекционное представление карты,
>   элементы которой принадлежат этому классу. Только способ получить
>   ссылку на запись карты от итератора этой коллекции ракурса. Эти
>   объекты Map.Entry действительны только в течение итерации; более
>   формально, поведение записи карты не определено, если базовая карта
>   была изменена после того, как запись была возвращена итератором, за
>   исключением операции setValue в записи карты.

Не очень понимаю зачем мы делаем вот это:

```
Map.Entry <Integer, String> entry: map.entrySet()
```

Сначали  Тип потом Переменная потом Коллекция/Массив, но не очень понимаю зачем писать Map.Entry  + потом еще не просто map, а именно map.entrySet().

 Помогите разобрать понятным и простым языком, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элемент, по которому вы хотите пробежаться с использованием конструкции [for-each](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) цикла должен реализовывать интерфейс [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Поскольку `Map` не реализует `Iterable`, вам нужно преобразовать его в некую иную форму, которая будет `Iterable`. Собственно, это и делает метод `entrySet`, возвращает вам `Set` пар ключ-значение (т.е. `Set<Map.Entry>`), а `Set` является `Iterable`.
`Map.Entry` - это просто интерфейс `Entry`, который представляет собой пару ключ-значение, пишем мы `Map.Entry`, потому что `Entry` - интерфейс, определенный в классе `Map`, так называемый `Nested-интерфейс`.